# Bootstrap Modal INSIDE Coldfusion <cfoutput query> tags fails with "Invalid CFML construct"

Tags: coldfusion, bootstrap-modal, cfoutput

The Bootstrap button and modal code below fails when the code is placed inside ColdFusion CFOUTPUT QUERY tags.

If I move the code outside of the cfoutput query then it works well.

Obviously, the problem is with the BootStrap modal single hashtag requirement: **target="#staticBackdrop"** for the button.

Inside the cfoutput, coldfusion expects two hashtags. The modal does not function without the single hashtag.

Is there a work-around?

```
<cfoutput query="q_GetPrinters">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
  DELETE
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" name="staticBackdrop" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Delete Printer?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
<!---      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>--->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is double up the hashtags to create one single tag in the generated HTML. Like `data-bs-target="##staticBackdrop"`. You also need to be aware that your code is within a `cfoutput` loop, so there will be mulitple lines generated all with the same ids, like `staticBackdrop`. You will need to add an incrementing number or something to make all of those ids unique.

Comment: FWIW, I would think you want a single modal that opens for every button you click. The data related to the `delete` call should be associated to the button, not the modal. The modal is just returning a `confirm` to the JavaScript on the button's click event, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double hashes for mentioning ids in ColdFusion like,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="##staticBackdrop">
```

Reason for this double hash is, in CF hash is used for outputting as it can be enclosed with variable name. While you writing target as #staticBackDrop, it will consider it as a variable name & hashes are not enclosed properly. So you re getting error like this.